# How can I calculate the local time differences using hours and minutes in Java?

Tags: java, time

I have a problem about calculating time differences in Java. In my entity, **departureTime** and **arriveTime** were defined as **string**.

When I calculate the differences by returning the result of calculateDuration method. I only get integer value

For example,

departureTime and arriveTime defined below.

"departureTime": "9:00",
"arriveTime": "11:30",

I want to get this value as **2.5** instead of getting **2**.

How can I do that?

Here are some code snippets shown below.

```
private long calculateDuration()
{

   final LocalDateTime departureDate =
   LocalDateTime.of(0, 1, 1, getHours(departureTime), getMinutes(departureTime));
        
   final LocalDateTime arrivalDate =
   LocalDateTime.of(0, 1, 1, getHours(arriveTime), getMinutes(arriveTime));

   return Duration.between(departureDate, arrivalDate).toHours();
}

private int getHours(final String time) {
    return Integer.parseInt(time.split(":")[0]);
}

private int getMinutes(final String time) {
    return Integer.parseInt(time.split(":")[1]);
}
```

Comment: I would recommend to use `LocalTime` for both `departureTime` and `arrivalTime` in your entity, instead of `String`.

Comment: @MCEmperor I want to get this value as 2.30 instead of getting 2. It is my issue.

Comment: I know that, and there's already an answer to your question out there. The only thing you need to do is replace `"h"` with `"."` and remove `"m"`. You should really be able to do that yourself.

Comment: @MCEmperor I get the value as a Double not String.

Comment: What do you mean? You're not using `Double` anywhere in your question.

Comment: @MCEmperor I just shared my answer.

Comment: `(double) Duration.between(departureDate, arrivalDate).toSeconds() / Duration.ofHours(1).toSeconds()` yields 2.5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer shown below.

```
Duration duration = Duration.between(departureDate, arrivalDate);

double result = duration.toHours() + duration.toMinutesPart()/60f;
```

Comment: This'll yield a value of `2.5`, and not `2.30`. You should edit the question to make your requirements clear.

Comment: @MCEmperor I just updated my post. I revised it.

Answer (score 3):

You can combine `toMinutesPart()` and `toHoursPart()` methods from `Duration` in order to get your exact time duration (java >= 9).

Example:

```
  public static void performDuration(LocalDateTime startTime, LocalDateTime endTime) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(startTime);
    Objects.requireNonNull(endTime);
    Duration between = Duration.between(startTime, endTime);
    System.out.println(between.toHoursPart() + "h" + between.toMinutesPart() + "m");
  }
```

if you call this method, with some given parameters:

```
performDuration(LocalDateTime.now().minusMinutes(150), LocalDateTime.now());
```

your result will be:

```
2h30m
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I only get 2.30 instead of 2h30m.

Comment: I get the value as a Double not String (2.30)

Comment: Ok, so, if you want the duration as a double, you can get 2.3, like this: `Double.valueOf(duration.toHoursPart()+ "." + duration.toMinutesPart())`, but, if you want it as a string, 2.30, you can do this: `String output = duration.toHoursPart()+ "." + duration.toMinutesPart(); return output;` Your method return type is long, so you cannot have neither 2.30 nor 2.3.

Comment: @TonyBrand the fractional number `2.30` is **not** a correct representation of 2½ hours. That should be `2.5` instead.

Comment: Yes, you can represent it like this: `BigDecimal.valueOf(duration.toMillis()).divide(BigDecimal.valueOf(1000), 4, RoundingMode.HALF_UP).divide(BigDecimal.valueOf(60), 4, RoundingMode.HALF_UP).divide(BigDecimal.valueOf(60), 2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP)`. The result will be 2.50